# c# using a runtime created listview

Tags: c#, listview, reference, identifier

Briefely;

I have button1 in my program. its create a new item in ListBox + new listview and rename listView every time its clicked. with another button I try to add data into selected listview but Im not able to figure out how to use newly created listviews name to access ListView class methods in program.

```
ListView yeni = new ListView();
 panel5.Controls.Add(yeni);
 yeni.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(liste_konum[0], liste_konum[1]);
 yeni.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(324, 106);
 yeni.GridLines = true;
 yeni.FullRowSelect = true;
 yeni.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(162)));
 yeni.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
 yeni.Columns.Add("Ada" + Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items.Count), 370);
 yeni.Name = "ListView" + Convert.ToString(liste_say);
```

(liste_say is a counter)
new created Listview has a name like "ListView5". how can ı access methods in another button click event. when "instance5" selected ı want to add some data to ListView5.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    

    {
     listView1.Items.Add("");
     listViev+Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1).Items.Add("somethink");
    }
```

This is not valid. Is there any think like using string or reference in identifiers?like:

```
String example = Convert.Tostring(expnumber);
ListView<example>.Items.Add("example");
```

Thanks for help. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, you're trying to access newly created controls at different points of execution.

One way you can do this is by keeping a `List` of `ListView` in your class and then pushing new `ListView` instances into it.

```
class Form 
{
  protected List<ListView> ListViews = new List<ListView>();
  
  private void AddListViewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
    var yeni = new ListView();
    listViews.Add(yeni);
  }

  private void AccessExistingListView()
  {
    // ... code to access your list view goes here
  }
}
```

Comment: Than you for your support.